# application android and ASP.NET

Tags: android

I write this code for connection android application to server ASP.NET 3.5,
this code it works in my laptop , but when I install this app in my mobile 
it doesn't working

I think that I should change IP 10.0.0.2 
but when I put my laptop IP it does't work too

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final String URL="http://10.0.0.2:42767/MathService/Service.asmx";

    public final String METHOD_NAME="GetAllString";

    public final String ACTION="http://tempuri.org/GetAllString";

    public final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
    public static String doo ="START";
    public static String [] Result = null;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



        return true;

    }
    public void CCC (View V) throws InterruptedException{


        EditText getinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo Pi = new PropertyInfo();

        Pi.setName("str");

        String ss= getinput.getText().toString();

        Pi.setValue(ss);

        Pi.setType(String.class);

        Request.addProperty(Pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envolope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);

        envolope.dotNet = true;

        envolope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        son htpm = new son(URL,500000);

        SoapObject response = null;

        String [] ArrayOfString = null;

        int number  = 0;

        try

        {
            htpm.call(ACTION,envolope);

            response = (SoapObject) envolope.getResponse();

            ArrayOfString = new String [response.getPropertyCount()];

            for (int j=0;;j++)
            {
                number ++;
                ArrayOfString[j] = response.getPropertyAsString(j);
                if(ArrayOfString[j].equals("Finish")) 
                    break;
            }

            //---link to Activity2---
            Intent i = new Intent(this,ACT2.class);
            i.putExtra("arg1",number-2);
            for(int a=1;a<number-1;a++)
                i.putExtra("str"+Integer.toString(a),ArrayOfString[a]);
            startActivityForResult(i, number-1);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextView textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
            textout.setText("error");
        }





    }



}
```

Comment: What's the error messages/stack and also since you have an ASMX service is your connectivity all correct? Verify that the service is accessible from the phone browser (Firewalls, security, addresses etc etc)

Comment: it is enter to catch and write error in text view
I am beginner in network , how I can Verify that the service is accessible from the phone browser

Comment: I turn off firewall ,it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you write the ASMX service? I don't know how to test your service - only you know the functionality. If you can't even get the browser to speak to it then you need learn this first. Here is a link to help you do that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719483(v=vs.71).aspx. Once you've confirmed connection then you can put that URL in to your app.